# Android exception handling

Tags: android, exception, android-alertdialog

I'm having trouble handling an exception called by a method. What I'm trying to do is create an alert dialog whenever an exception is caught (I know how to create the alert dialog). The method throwing the exception is in a different class, which is why I can't create an alert dialog when the exception is caught. See below:-

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) { 

    try{
        ParserLive parser = new ParserLive();
        feeds = parser.parse(); // this is the method throwing the exception
        return true;  //won't return true because it gets stuck here
    } catch (Throwable t){
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Below is the ParserLive class where the method is:-

```
public class ParserLive {

       //variables and constructor
       //Below is the method I want to handle

       //Ideally I'd like to wrap the code inside this method with a try-catch, 
       //and put the dialog in the catch statement, but this is not allowed.
       public List<Feed> parse() {
       //some code 
       // the following code is throwing the error, when I try to create an alert dialog inside this catch statement it says "the constructor AlertDialog.Builder(ParserLive) is undefined"
       try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
       } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e); 
         }
     return feeds;
  }
}
```

#### EDIT

I've edited the above code to include the line of code throwing the following error in LogCat - " java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found
"

Comment: Please post your logcat. When do you throw the exception in your code?

Comment: What do you mean: "//won't return true because it gets stuck here"?

Comment: So you are asking how to create a dialog when the exception is caught..?

Comment: what about putting „feeds = parser.parse();“ into a try-catch-construct and declare ParserLive.parse as throwing an Exception?

Comment: I've edited my question, hopefully will clarify things. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) { 
            try{
                ParserLive parser = new ParserLive();
                feeds = parser.parse(); 
                return true;  
            } catch (Exception e){
                log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
                yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                  public void run() {
                                      Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), 3000).show();        }
                                 });
//Here you can create dialog also
                return false;
            }    
        }
```